# Vertical scaling with Raphael (transform)

Tags: raphael

I have a question regarding vertical scaling with Raphael using transform. I tried the following code:

```
var transform = "sx"+dx;
selRect.transform(transform);
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Anyone ideas how to solve this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
var transform = "S1," + dx;
```

Also, don't forget you can optionally indicate the point you want to scale around...  so

```
var bbox = selRect.getBBox();
var transform1 = "S1," + dx + ",0,0";
var transform2 = "S1," + dx + "," + ( bbox.width / 2 ) + "," + ( bbox.height / 2 );
```

Will offset the resulting rect differently.  It can certainly come in handy on occasion!